# Packaging an unmanaged package with Tabs settings

Tags: force.com

We have created a new App having few Custom objects (with associated Tabs) and few Standard Tabs (Opportunity, Product etc.), now when we package this App and install this to another account, we are expecting to display all required Tabs by default i.e. user shouldn't be required to customize the Tabs and turn on the desired Tabs.

The Problem is, all the Custom Tabs are displayed at the target account except the Standard Tabs.

How we can do this?

Comment: After installing the package check in target account's profile whether this tabs are hidden or not.

Comment: Tabs are not hidden, user will just have to go to "Customize My Tabs" and select the required for this App and Save. Now Tabs will be there for the App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto your App in the setup menu

```
Create -> App -> Your App name
```

Click on Edit next to your App name. Scroll down to the multi select list `Choose the tabs`

Add the tabs that you want to include in your App. These tabs would be visible on the client org when they open your App.

Hope this helps